# prevent caching WEB API data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. This application requests records through WEB API web service. WEB API calls back to a exctetion method that returns results in JSON format. I have not been able to prove this, but I'm concerned that my data may be getting cached.

I only want the caching to be applied to specific actions, not for all actions.

Is there an attribute that I can put on an action to ensure that the data does not get cached? If not, how do I ensure that the browser gets a new set of records each time, instead of a cached set?

I put the below attributes on action to ensure that the data do not get cached.But do not work correctly after insert data. So after reset IIS effected the changes.

```
[System.Web.Mvc.OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [NoCache]
    public List<DataModel> Get()
    {

        var result= ExtMethod.GetData();
        return result;

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your ExtMethod is static. That might be the reason.

Comment: @Selçuk yes that's static method

Comment: Can you add your ExtMethod class code?

Comment: @Selçuk Yes,I do

Answer (score 0):

I'm with an ASP.NET MVC5 application as well and added the `OutputCache` directives to my regular Controllers and my API controller. I still had some caching going on still. It seemed to help in my case to move the cache prevention code into a central location: to the `App_Start/FilterConfig.cs`'s `RegisterGlobalFilters` method:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        // ...
        filters.Add(new OutputCacheAttribute
        {
            NoStore = true,
            Duration = 0,
            VaryByParam = "*",
            Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.None
        });
    }
}
```

Once I had that in place I could remove the individual directives from the various `Controller`s. The downside of this is if you'd want to enable caching from any of the controllers, but my understanding is that you can override the global filter by applying a different `OutputCache` directive at `Controller` or `View` level.